# 2 divs floating right wrong aligment

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

I have three divs. I want to float last two left, next to the 1st. But the 2nd one floats  after the 3ed one. 
why is that?

Thank you!

this is my code:

HTML

```
<div id="holder_idea"><h5>something</h5></div>
<div id="visual_holder_second">something2</div>
<div id="invest">
<h2>something3</h2></div>
```

CSS

```
#holder_idea{
width:200px;
padding-right:48px;
padding-left:32px;
padding-top:32px;
display:inline-block;
}

#visual_holder_second{
font-family: "Times New Roman";
font-size:7.5em;
text-transform:uppercase;
line-height:60%;
width:140px;
float:right;
padding-top:32px;
}

#invest{float:right;}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to float left, why are you floating right?..

Apply float left to all three divs: http://jsfiddle.net/ngztf/

Your 140px width is a lot smaller than your actual content (that i reduced to 3.5em for testing purposes).

```
div {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
#holder_idea {
    width:200px;
    padding-right:48px;
    padding-left:32px;
    padding-top:32px;
}
#visual_holder_second {
    font-family:"Times New Roman";
    font-size:3.5em;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    line-height:60%;
    width:140px;
    padding-top:32px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I pressume you want it to look like this

```
 | div1 | div2|
 |      | div3|
```

If so, please recall that float puts the div outside normal flow of object, and makes it "stick" as close to the previous element on the side, going to the next line only if there is no longer any space in the previous one. 
An example:http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_image_gallery
(yes, I know w3schools is evil)
Notice how positions change together with window size change.

Comment: i want them all in same line    div1 /div2 /div3

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `float: right;`'s to `float: left;` and remove the `width: 140px` on `#visual_holder_second`.

And actually, if you're going for a multicolumn layout, don't be afraid to use good ol' tables. They got a bad rap from abuse in the 90's, but they still have their place.

Comment: Use code formatting instead of double quotes, for a better readability